# Retrieve content from other page

Tags: php, jquery, html

This is a follow up to a previous question.

I've got an icon when I click it the icon changes and calls `go.php?go=`
When you click it again, the icon reverts back to the original icon and calls `go.php?stop=`

This works. Currently go.php just writes the correct info to a text file, ideally i'd like to see the output from go.php reflected into a DIV on the parent page that has the icons..

How do I do that ?

This is what I have so far..

```
<script language="javascript">
$(function () {
    $('a.tip').on(' click', function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            container = $('#x')
            prevHTML = container.html(),
            req = {};

        if ( $this.hasClass('go') ) {
            $this.find('img').attr('src', 'images/go.gif');
            $this.removeClass('go');
            req = $.ajax({
                url: 'go.php?go=' + $this.attr('id'),
                type: 'get',
                success: function ( data ) {
                    container.html(x);
                    $this.removeClass('go');
                }
            });
        } else {
            $this.find('img').attr('src', 'images/stop.gif')
                .end().addClass('go');
            req = $.ajax({
                url: 'go.php?stop=' + $this.attr('id'),
                type: 'get',
                success: function ( data ) {
                    container.html( x );
                    $this.removeClass('go');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>    

<a href='#' class='tip' id='4a' onclick=\"load('#');return false;\">
    <img src='images/go.gif'>
</a>
<a href='#' class='tip' id='6a' onclick=\"load('#');return false;\">
    <img src='images/go.gif'>
</a>
<a href='#' class='tip' id='8a' onclick=\"load('#');return false;\">
    <img src='images/go.gif'>
</a>
```

go.php contains:

```
<?php
   $s = (isset($_REQUEST['go'])) ? "GO".$_REQUEST['go'] : "STOP".$_REQUEST['stop'];
   $myFile = "TESTTEST.txt";
   $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
   $stringData = $s;
   fwrite( $fh, $stringData );
   fclose( $fh );
   echo $s;
?>
```

UPDATE:
This appears to work :

```
<script language="javascript">
$(function () {
    $('a.tip').on(' click', function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            container = $('#x')
            prevHTML = container.html(),
            req = {};

        if ($this.hasClass('go')) {
            $this.find('img').attr('src', 'images/ok.gif');
            $this.removeClass('go');
            req = $.ajax({
                url: 'go.php?go=' + $this.attr('id'),
                type: 'get',
                success: function (data) {
                    container.html(data);
                    $this.removeClass('go');
                }
            });
        } else {
            $this.find('img').attr('src', 'images/error.gif')
                .end().addClass('go');
            req = $.ajax({
                url: 'go.php?stop=' + $this.attr('id'),
                type: 'get',
                success: function (data) {
                    container.html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change this line:

```
container.html(x);
```

To this:

```
container.html(data);
```

`data` is the variable containing the text returned from the AJAX request.

Comment: Thanks, changing this does show the results.. BUT. stops the second click reverting the icon and value. any ideas ?

Comment: In the update you removed the `addClass('go')` right? That should have fixed the logic flow in the `if` condition. Does it worjk as you need it to now?

Comment: I removed the `$this.removeClass('go');` that does seem to make it work !

Comment: @user1635970 Glad it helped. Don't forget to click the green tick on the left if this answer worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
container.html(x);
```

should have been

```
container.html(data);
```

Comment: Thanks, changing this does show the results.. BUT. stops the second click reverting the icon and value. any ideas ?